# Types with Math.net numerics

Tags: math.net

I am starting to use the `Math.net` numerics library and I can't find examples, so I'm running into a few issues:

To make a simple example, I have two arrays of `double`s. I want to divide one by the other and then calculate the moving average.

So, the code looks like this:

```
var VD1 = Vector<double>.Build.Dense(Data1.ToArray());
var VD2 = Vector<double>.Build.Dense(Data2.ToArray());
var R = VD1 / VD2;
var SMA = R.MovingAverage(15);
```

The problem is that, on the way, the data type changes. It starts as 2 `Vector`s, the division result is a `Vector` and the `SMA` result is not, it's an `IEnumerable<double>`.

So, now if I want to plug that result into more functions, for example multiply it by another array, I can't. I have to rebuild a `Vector` from the result.

Am I somehow doing this wrong? I can't imagine that the API would bounce back and forth between different but similar types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are doing it right.** That is how `MathNet` is designed. E.g., `var R = VD1 / VD2;` calls

```
// Summary: Pointwise divides two Vectors.
public static Vector<T> operator /(Vector<T> dividend, Vector<T> divisor);
```

and returns `Vector<T>`.

`var SMA = R.MovingAverage(15);` calls

```
public static IEnumerable<double> MovingAverage(this IEnumerable<double> samples, int windowSize);
```

and returns `IEnumerable<double>`.

You can call `MovingAverage` with `Vector<double>` `R`, because `Vector<double>` implements `IEnumerable<double>` and you get **implicit casting**. But `MovingAverage` does not know its argument is `Vector<double>`, it's designed to return `IEnumerable<double>`.
And that makes sense. As far as I remember from colledge, moving average is about time series and it has no explicit relationship to vectors.

But you can have some workarounds. For example your own overload for `MovingAverage`:

```
static class VectorHeplper
{
    public static Vector<double> MovingAverage(this Vector<double> samples, int windowSize)
    {
        return DenseVector.OfEnumerable(samples.AsEnumerable().MovingAverage(windowSize));
    }
}
```

Then `var SMA = R.MovingAverage(15);` is `Vector<double>`.

Anyway, building a new instance of `Vector` is the **right and logical** way.